# How to generate many to many relationship data with Bogus in .Net core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, bogus

Hi guys I have a problem about Bogus. Firstly please check my sample below.

```
public class Student
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public List<StudentLaptop> StudentLaptops { get; set; }
}
public class Laptop
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public string Brand { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<StudentLaptop> StudentLaptops { get; set; }
}
public class StudentLaptop
{
    public Guid StudentId { get; set; }
    public Guid LaptopId { get; set; }
    public Laptop Laptop { get; set; }
    public Student Student { get; set; }
}

public class AppDbContext: DbContext
{
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("constring");
        }
    }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Laptop> Laptops { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StudentLaptop> StudentLaptops { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentLaptop>().HasOne(a => a.Student).WithMany(a => a.StudentLaptops);
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentLaptop>().HasOne(a => a.Laptop).WithMany(a => a.StudentLaptops);
        modelBuilder.Entity<StudentLaptop>().HasKey(a=> new {a.StudentId, a.LaptopId});
        Seed(modelBuilder);
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
    private void Seed(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        DataGenerator.Initialize(modelBuilder);
    }
}
 public class DataGenerator
 {

     public static void Initialize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
     {

         var studentFaker = new StudentFaker();
         var laptopFaker = new LaptopFaker();

         var fakeStudent = studentFaker.Generate(5);
         var fakeLaptop = laptopFaker.Generate(3);
         var studentLaptopFaker = new StudentLaptopFaker(fakeStudent,fakeLaptop);
         var fakeStudentLaptop = studentLaptopFaker.Generate(15);


         modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().HasData(fakeStudent);
         modelBuilder.Entity<Laptop>().HasData(fakeLaptop);
         modelBuilder.Entity<StudentLaptop>().HasData(fakeStudentLaptop);

     }
     public class StudentFaker : Faker<Student>
     {
         public StudentFaker()
         {
             RuleFor(a => a.Id, f => f.Random.Guid());
             RuleFor(g => g.Name, f => f.Person.FullName);
             RuleFor(g => g.Age, f => f.Random.Number(100));
         }
     }

     public class LaptopFaker : Faker<Laptop>
     {
         public LaptopFaker()
         {
             RuleFor(a => a.Id, f => f.Random.Guid());
             RuleFor(l => l.Brand, f => f.Commerce.Product());
             RuleFor(l => l.Name, f => f.Commerce.ProductName());
         }
     }
     public class StudentLaptopFaker : Faker<StudentLaptop>
     {
         public StudentLaptopFaker(List<Student>students, List<Laptop> laptops)
         {
             RuleFor(sl => sl.StudentId, f => f.PickRandom(students).Id);
             RuleFor(sl => sl.LaptopId, f => f.PickRandom(laptops).Id);
         }
     }
 }
```

As you can see above I have declared some rules. But I have a migration error like this;

'The seed entity for entity type 'StudentLaptop' cannot be added because another seed entity with the same key value for {'StudentId', 'LaptopId'} has already been added. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.'.

If you guys help me I will be very appreciate it.

Comment: Based on your code the error stems from generating duplicate StudentLaptop entities with the same StudentId and LaptopId combinations, violating the composite primary key constraint.
Make sure,  distinct StudentId and LaptopId pairings during generation. You can track generated pairs to prevent duplicates.

Comment: You could create stacks of the lists and pass those to the `StudentLaptopFaker` and call `.Pop()` instead of `PickRandom`, but you have to make sure you have enough in the stack or allow for null values.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron  I have tried your suggestion but problem is still same